# Роутинг для единой точки входа

Tags: php, mvc, route

Возникла проблема.

Есть GET параметры:q,offset,POST параметры act,user.
В GET параметре q содержится строка для поискового запроса. В GET параметры offset страница.

В POST параметре act могут быть значения add_user,add_name других нет никаких. В POST параметре user числовое значение пользователя.
Для файла handler.php могут быть следующие состояния:

> GET- handler.php?q=search_string&offset=40

Для

> POST handler.php act=add_user&user=6298

или

> act=add_name&user=6298

GET запросы отдают html код страницы, а POST json ответы.

Смешивают GET и POST и в результате на

> handler.php?q=search_string&offset=40

может придти еще и

> POST act=add_user&user=6298

а также куча других act'ов

Скрипт в результате обрабатывает и GET и POST и получается не то что нужно. Как с этим можно бороться?

Чтобы если пришли GET запросы любые POST запросы даже если присутствовали, но не повредили и наоборот.
Что-то слышал про front-controller,route,mvc но сколько не читаю информации никто такую проблему не описывает и не решает.

Может какие-нибудь *AltoRoute, Slim, Yii, Laravel* надо хитро применить, просто уже не знаю что и делать.

Comment: А `$_POST` запросы вы берёте из `$_REQUEST` ?

Comment: Нет, из $_POST['']

Comment: Тогда объясняйте, как могут повлиять ключи $_POST на выборку для $_GET параметров? Далее, не нужные гет параметры можно отсечь в .htaccess c 301 редиректом.

Comment: Что? я вас не понял совсем.

Comment: _Скрипт в результате обрабатывает и GET и POST и получается не то что нужно. Как с этим можно бороться?_ Все зависит от вашей логике в коде. Не нужно - не обрабатывайте POST или GET. Вопроса как такого  нет

Comment: Хорошо.Понял.Спасибо.