# Роутинг для одной точки входа

Tags: php, post, mvc, get, route

Как сделать для запросов вида:

```
index.php POST act=add&user_id=1&param1=data1&..&paramN=dataN
```

Грамотный роутинг? Что здесь будет контроллер, что модель?
потому что могут быть и такие строки:

```
index.php POST act=delete&user_id=1&param1=data1&..&paramN=dataN

index.php POST act=selection&user_id=1&param1=data1&..&paramN=dataN
```

мне `GET` вида:`controller/model/param1/param2/param3` не нужен.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Роутинг для единой точки входа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827687/%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: Может я не правильно понял вопрос, но почему же get запрос должен быть именно таким, controller/model/param1/param2/param3, когда можно перенаправлять на index.php, а он в зависимости от того что тебе нужно будет выдавать, да даже почему именно post запрос, когда есть put, get, post, delete

Comment: То есть принципы rest или других похожих архитектур. Или же если используется MVC (если правильно понял), это же не означает что адрес будет controler/model/catalog

Comment: MVC архитектура

Comment: это то или же тебе нужно именно пример под тебя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно, вот смотри когда я смотрел как это работает, делал примерно так

index.php

```
<?php
function Scan($dir)
{
    if (!preg_match("/\.$/",$dir)){
       if (is_file($dir))  require_once($dir);
        else {
            $d=opendir("$dir");
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($d)))
                Scan("$dir/$file");
            closedir($d);
        }
    }
}
require_once('config.php');
Scan("./classes");
Scan("./controllers");
Scan("./models");
$bootstrap = new Bootstrap;
$controller = $bootstrap->createController();
if($controller) {
  $controller->executeAction();
}
```

bootstrap class

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
class Bootstrap
{
  private $controller;
  private $action;
  private $request;
  function __construct()
  { 
    // разбираешь url
    $this->request = explode('/', mb_substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 1)); 
    // смотришь полученные параметры на наличие home page
    if($this->request[0] == '') {
      $this->controller = 'home';
    }
    else {
      $this->controller = $this->request[0];
    }
    if(!isset($this->request[1]) || $this->request[1] == '') {
      $this->action = 'index';
    } else {
      $this->action = $this->request[1];
    }
  }
  public function createController() {
    // проверяешь на наличие того или иного контроллера
    if(class_exists($this->controller) ) {
      $parents = class_parents($this->controller);
      if( in_array("Controller", $parents) ) {
         // здесь уже смотришь на наличие действий
        if( method_exists($this->controller, $this->action ) ) {
          return new $this->controller($this->action, $this->request);
        }
        else {
          echo " <h1>Method does not exist </h1> ";
          return;
        }
      } else {
        echo "<h1>Base controller not found</h1>";
        return;
      }
    } else {
      echo "<h1>Controller class does not found</h1>";
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

И выходит по два параметра к примеру: `user/login`, controller:action
А action уже сам разбирается, что он будет вытаскивать

На github есть полный код, только без комментариев разбирать сложно 
https://github.com/KaukinDima/php/tree/master/mvc/MVCmyCRUD

Comment: спасибо очень похожее на мой пример.

Comment: а как понять пример под меня?сильно будет отличаться?

Comment: видишь здесь больше под блог идет, то есть особо не разогнаться, а у тебя вариант подходит под rest архитектуру, то есть делается, api/product/some_action, в telegram такой же метод используется, https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/METHOD_NAME, просто я не уверен что здесь нужно mvc, вот это файл bootstrap, будет примерно такой же, а дальше по-другому, вот ссылки посмотри, https://torquemag.io/2016/08/building-custom-rest-api-routes-using-object-oriented-php/, http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Comment: Спасибо.Буду пробовать.